# Pdfkit not generating pdf file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having problem in pdf generation. I have used two gems "pdfkit" and wkhtmltopdf-binary.
I have model student.In that model show page shows for particular student details. So the url will be "http://www.example.com:3000/students/38".when I gave 38.pdf in url .It won't show any pdf file instead of that the url was loading continually.

Gemfile

```
 gem "pdfkit"
 gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

``
In application.rb

```
config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware"
```

Comment: Have you added the format.pdf on the respond_to block for students#show ?